# Can a forms authentication cookie .ASPXAUTH be used to assign a user to a MVC 5 OWIN application's context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, owin

Can a .ASPXAUTH forms authentication cookie be used in an MVC 5 OWIN-based application to create a user in the HttpContext.User property?

Both applications share the same machineKey and the domain/server are the same. The .ASPXAUTH cookie is also available in the MVC 5 application's OwinContext.Request.Cookies collection.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 5 OWIN-based project:

You should think about several things.

That's how it works for me:

1. Do all things described in [this article](http://www.alexboyang.com/2014/05/28/sso-for-asp-net-mvc4-and-mvc5-web-apps-shared-the-same-domain/) (see also [github project](https://gist.github.com/AlexBoYang/760ed4bf54587cc27aaa))

   - Dont forget set up "compatibilityMode" for machineKey tag in web.config in BOTH projects
     for example `<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" validationKey="..."/>`
   - `validationKey`, `decryptionKey`, `validation` and `description` should be the same in both sites.
2. Then I had rewrite methods Protect

   ```
   public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
   {
       var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
           2, data.Identity.Name, 
           DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), true, "");
       var ret = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
       return ret;
   }
   ```

   because the ticked described by Alex Yang was "dead" (expired), and Unprotect

   ```
   public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
   {
       var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(protectedText);
       var mngr = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
                   .GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
       var user = mngr.FindByName(ticket.Name);
       var identity = mngr.CreateIdentity(
                        user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
       return new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
   }
   ```

   because `OnValidateIdentity` didnt work properly for me and Alex Yang created for output new `FormsAuthenticationIdentity`, but i needed `ClaimsIdentity`.
3. If you want to use version by Alex Yang, dont forget add method used in OnValidateIdentity that he had forgot to describe :) Add it to your AppUser class

   ```
   public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
   UserManager<AppUser> manager)
   {
       // Note the authenticationType must match the one 
       // defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
       var userIdentity =
           await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,
               DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
       // Add custom user claims here
       return userIdentity;
   }
   ```

After i done that, in both sites `.ASPXAUTH` cookie was accepted/generated right.